# How can I check if any button of a two dimensional array was clicked?

Tags: arrays, delphi, minesweeper

I am trying to build a minesweeper program. So far, I made a two-dimensional array of buttons with the variable `Buttons[rows][cols]`, so you can target every button on the field. The buttons are created on the form at runtime. Now I need to know how I can determine whether a button was clicked.

I know you can check `if Sender = Button` but how does it work with two-dimensional arrays? And since I created the Buttons at runtime (FormCreate), how do I create the procedure in which the code can be executed, because it certainly shouldn't check if a button was clicked at runtime.

Would anyone be so kind and show me how I can disable a button after it was clicked? For this, obviously, I need to know how to determine which button was clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the buttons, set their `Tag` property to an ID:

```
Button.Tag := Col + Row*ColCount;
```

Give each button the same `OnClick` event handler.

```
Button.OnClick := ButtonClick;
```

These two lines of code will be inside a loop like this:

```
for Row := 0 to RowCount-1 do
  for Col := 0 to ColCount-1 do
  begin
    Button := TButton.Create(Self);
    Button.Parent := Self;
    Button.Left := ...;
    Button.Top := ...;
    Button.Tag := ...;
    Button.OnClick := ...;
    Buttons[Row,Col] := Button;
  end;
```

I expect you already have code like this.

Implement the event handler to decode the ID like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Button: TButton;
  Row, Col: Integer;
begin
  Button := Sender as TButton;
  Row := Button.Tag div ColCount;
  Col := Button.Tag mod ColCount;
  // respond to click
end;
```

Disable a control by setting its `Enabled` property to `False`.

Here I've assumed zero based indexing, and that your buttons are `TButton`. If these assumptions are wrong, you'll clearly need to adapt to your scenario.

I think this answers the question you asked. However, using a button for each grid square is probably the wrong way to implement Minesweeper. You would be better off with a `TPaintBox`, a non-visual structure to hold the state, and a single `OnClick` handler for the paint box.

Comment: A definitive +1 for the given alternative :o)

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot! Due to the fact that it is a school project, we decided to use buttons so I could not change that, thanks anyway for the given alternative :)